# how to run gradle web project on Tomee web server?

Tags: gradle, jakarta-ee, netbeans, apache-tomee

I'm working on a website. This is my gradle file:

```
buildscript{
    repositories{
        mavenCentral();
        jcenter();
    }
    dependencies{
        classpath("org.hibernate:hibernate-gradle-plugin:5.4.2.Final");
        classpath("org.apache.tomee.gradle:tomee-embedded:8.0.0");
    }
}

plugins{
    id("java");
    id("war");
    id("org.hibernate.gradle.tools") version("1.2.5");
}
apply plugin: "org.hibernate.orm";
apply plugin: "org.apache.tomee.tomee-embedded";

allprojects{
    repositories{
        mavenCentral();
        jcenter();
    }
}
version = "1.0";
sourceCompatibility = "1.8";
targetCompatibility = "1.8";

tasks.withType(JavaCompile){
    options.encoding = "UTF-8";
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        resources {
            srcDirs = [
                'src/main/webapp',
                'src/main/resources'
            ]
        }
    }
}

dependencies{
    def jsfVersion = "2.2.20";
    def hibernateValidatorVersion = "6.0.17.Final";
    def prettyfacesVersion = "3.4.2.Final";

    // JavaEE Components
    providedCompile("javax:javaee-api:8.0.1");

    // Servlet EE Components
    providedCompile("javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:4.0.1");

    compile("javax.validation:validation-api:2.0.1.Final");

    // Expression Language Components

    compile("org.glassfish:javax.el:3.0.1-b11");

    // Mysql Components
    compile("mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.17");

    // Hibernate Components
    compile(
        "org.hibernate:hibernate-core:6.0.0.Alpha2",
        "org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:5.4.4.Final",
        "org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:$hibernateValidatorVersion",
        "org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator-annotation-processor:$hibernateValidatorVersion",
        "org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:1.0.2.Final",
        "org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache:5.4.4.Final"
    );

    // JSF Components
    compile(
        "com.sun.faces:jsf-api:$jsfVersion",
        "com.sun.faces:jsf-impl:$jsfVersion"
    );

    // Prettyfaces Components
    compile(
        "org.ocpsoft.rewrite:rewrite-servlet:$prettyfacesVersion",
        "org.ocpsoft.rewrite:rewrite-config-prettyfaces:$prettyfacesVersion"
    );

    // Log4j Components
    compile("log4j:log4j:1.2.17");

    // ICU4j Components
    compile("com.ibm.icu:icu4j:64.2");

    // junit Components
    compile("junit:junit:4.12");
    testCompile("junit:junit:4.12");
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.12");
}

war{
    archiveName = 'YeJayeKhoob.com.war'
    from("${projectDir}/src/main/webapp/");
    webXml = file("${projectDir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/Web.xml");
}

hibernate{
    enhance{
        enableLazyInitialization           = true;
        enableDirtyTracking                = true;
        enableExtendedEnhancement = false;
    }
}

test{
    useJUnit()
    maxHeapSize = '1G'
}

tasks.withType(JavaExec){
    if(System.getProperty('DEBUG', 'false') == 'true'){
        jvmArgs '-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005'
    }
}

task explodedWar(type: Sync){
    into    "${buildDir}/YJKWebApp" 
    with   war
} 
war.dependsOn explodedWar

def tomeeEmbedded = extensions.getByName("tomee-embedded");
tomeeEmbedded.tomeeVersion  = "8.0.0";
tomeeEmbedded.host = "localhost";
tomeeEmbedded.httpPort = 8081;
tomeeEmbedded.keepServerXmlAsThis = true;
tomeeEmbedded.skipDefaultRepository = true; // don't use central to retrieve tomee
//tomeeEmbedded.docBase = file("${buildDir}/YJKWebApp");
//tomeeEmbedded.modules=[project.file("${buildDir}/classes"), project.file("${buildDir}/resources")];
```

I use **tomee-embedded** plugin but I cannot run my project in netbeans. Instead, I use command line. But when i run gradle with **gradle tomee-embedded -i**, i get this error:

```
    Execution failed for task ':tomee-embedded'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':tomee-embedded'.
   > Could not find org.apache.tomee.patch:bval-jsr:2.0.2-69c36fa8-1.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - file:/C:/Users/Arash/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomee/patch/bval-jsr/2.0.2-69c36fa8-1/bval-jsr-2.0.2-69c36fa8-1.pom
       - file:/C:/Users/Arash/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomee/patch/bval-jsr/2.0.2-69c36fa8-1/bval-jsr-2.0.2-69c36fa8-1.jar
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/tomee/patch/bval-jsr/2.0.2-69c36fa8-1/bval-jsr-2.0.2-69c36fa8-1.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/tomee/patch/bval-jsr/2.0.2-69c36fa8-1/bval-jsr-2.0.2-69c36fa8-1.jar
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/tomee/patch/bval-jsr/2.0.2-69c36fa8-1/bval-jsr-2.0.2-69c36fa8-1.pom
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/tomee/patch/bval-jsr/2.0.2-69c36fa8-1/bval-jsr-2.0.2-69c36fa8-1.jar
     Required by:
         project : > org.apache.tomee:tomee-embedded:8.0.0-M3 > org.apache.tomee:openejb-core:8.0.0-M3
```

I tried to configure Tomee like this:

```
def tomeeEmbedded = extensions.getByName('tomee-embedded')
tomeeEmbedded.skipDefaultRepository  = true
```

But i got the error again. What's the problem? and how can i run my project in the Netbeans.

Web Server     : Apache TomEE Plus v8.0.0-M1

IDE            : Apache Netbeans 11

Gradle Version : 5.4.1

### **After**

excluding **bval-jsr** and adding **org.apache.bval:bval-jsr** as **[Romain Manni-Bucau](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56839482/how-to-run-gradle-web-project-on-tomee-web-server/57332574#57332574)** said, Netbeans shows me a warning : (I don't know how to copy the warning in the IDE)
[image]

But when i run **gradle tomee-embedded --stacktrace** command, i get this error :

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':tomee-embedded'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$3.accept(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:148)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$3.accept(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:145)
        at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:191)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:138)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveBeforeExecutionStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveBeforeExecutionStateTaskExecuter.java:75)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:62)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:108)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveBeforeExecutionOutputsTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveBeforeExecutionOutputsTaskExecuter.java:67)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveAfterPreviousExecutionStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveAfterPreviousExecutionStateTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:94)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:95)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:73)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:49)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:49)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:43)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:355)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:343)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:336)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:322)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:134)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:202)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:193)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException
        at org.apache.tomee.gradle.embedded.TomEEEmbeddedTask.doRun(TomEEEmbeddedTask.java:349)
        at org.apache.tomee.gradle.embedded.TomEEEmbeddedTask.runTomEEEmbedded(TomEEEmbeddedTask.java:205)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:103)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.doExecute(StandardTaskAction.java:48)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:41)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:28)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:702)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:669)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$5.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:401)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:402)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:394)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:92)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:390)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:373)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.access$200(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:79)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$TaskExecution.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:210)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.lambda$execute$1(ExecuteStep.java:33)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:33)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:26)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupOutputsStep.execute(CleanupOutputsStep.java:58)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupOutputsStep.execute(CleanupOutputsStep.java:35)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:48)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:33)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CancelExecutionStep.execute(CancelExecutionStep.java:39)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.executeWithoutTimeout(TimeoutStep.java:73)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.execute(TimeoutStep.java:54)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CatchExceptionStep.execute(CatchExceptionStep.java:35)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:51)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SnapshotOutputsStep.execute(SnapshotOutputsStep.java:45)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SnapshotOutputsStep.execute(SnapshotOutputsStep.java:31)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.executeWithoutCache(CacheStep.java:201)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:70)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:45)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.execute(BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.java:49)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreSnapshotsStep.execute(StoreSnapshotsStep.java:43)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreSnapshotsStep.execute(StoreSnapshotsStep.java:32)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:38)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:24)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.executeBecause(SkipUpToDateStep.java:96)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.lambda$execute$0(SkipUpToDateStep.java:89)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:54)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:38)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:77)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:37)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:36)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:26)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:90)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:48)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultWorkExecutor.execute(DefaultWorkExecutor.java:33)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:117)
        ... 35 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at org.apache.tomee.gradle.embedded.TomEEEmbeddedTask.doRun(TomEEEmbeddedTask.java:345)
        ... 88 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: javax.validation.ValidationException: HV000183: Unable to initialize 'javax.el.ExpressionFactory'. Check that you have the EL dependencies on the classpath, or use ParameterMessageInterpolator instead
        at org.apache.tomee.embedded.Container.deploy(Container.java:352)
        at org.apache.tomee.embedded.Container.deployPathsAsWebapp(Container.java:230)
        at org.apache.tomee.embedded.Container.deployClasspathAsWebApp(Container.java:195)
        at org.apache.tomee.embedded.Container.deployClasspathAsWebApp(Container.java:171)
        ... 89 more
Caused by: javax.validation.ValidationException: HV000183: Unable to initialize 'javax.el.ExpressionFactory'. Check that you have the EL dependencies on the classpath, or use ParameterMessageInterpolator instead
        at org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.buildExpressionFactory(ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.java:123)
        at org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.<init>(ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.java:47)
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl.getDefaultMessageInterpolator(ConfigurationImpl.java:474)
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl.getDefaultMessageInterpolatorConfiguredWithClassLoader(ConfigurationImpl.java:650)
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl.getMessageInterpolator(ConfigurationImpl.java:397)
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorFactoryImpl.<init>(ValidatorFactoryImpl.java:183)
        at org.hibernate.validator.HibernateValidator.buildValidatorFactory(HibernateValidator.java:38)
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl.buildValidatorFactory(ConfigurationImpl.java:364)
        at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.ValidatorBuilder.buildFactory(ValidatorBuilder.java:118)
        at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.ValidatorBuilder.buildFactory(ValidatorBuilder.java:71)
        at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.LazyValidatorFactory.ensureDelegate(LazyValidatorFactory.java:54)
        at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.LazyValidatorFactory.getFactory(LazyValidatorFactory.java:65)
        at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:977)
        at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:758)
        at org.apache.tomee.embedded.Container.deploy(Container.java:350)
        ... 92 more
```

### **After**

Defining **tomeeVersion** and adding:

```
tomeeEmbedded.docBase = file("${buildDir}/YJKWebApp");
```

as **[Romain Manni-Bucau](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56839482/how-to-run-gradle-web-project-on-tomee-web-server/57332574#57332574)** said, Tomee Embedded runs without error but doesn't finish. Just endless counting:

```
.
.
.
Loaded [0] org.ocpsoft.rewrite.spi.RuleCacheProvider []
Rewrite 3.4.2.Final initialized.
Deployed Application(path=)
TomEE embedded started on localhost:8081
<-------------> 0% EXECUTING [6m 24s]
> :tomee-embedded
```

and when i remove above config and add this one:

```
tomeeEmbedded.modules=[project.file("${buildDir}/classes"), project.file("${buildDir}/resources")];
```

the result is the same.

Answer (score 1):

M3 bval dependency is wrong, try to exclude it from tomee embedded and replace it with last oeg.apache.bval:bval-jsr one

Comment: Thanks Romain, But how can i do that? It seems **TomEE Embedded** needs **bval-jsr:2.0.2-69c36fa8-1** that doesn't exist.

Comment: In your gradle dependency, add an exclusion directly in gradle script. Tomee depends on bval-jsr, the apache.bval version works fine too and respects the spec (vs the forked version).

Comment: Thanks Romain. I excluded **bval-jsr** but i got **nullPointerException**.

Comment: Maybe share the full stack, but did you add org.apache.bval:bval-jsr at the same time?

Comment: Thanks @Romain, I Updated my question. Gradle Build File is changed.

Comment: Thanks @Romain, your comment on catalystOne's answer, removed the error. but **TomEE Embedded** plugin doesn't deploy the **war** on **TomEE** web server. I  configured TomEE Embedded. I updated gradle build in my question.

Comment: Tomee embedded gradle integration only deploys the classpath. If you set (pseudo code) modules=[classes,resources] in tomeeembedded extension then it should work. You can also set docBase=path to exploded webapp for web resources.

Comment: Thanks for your patience, @Romain. I did what you said(I updated my question and gradle file). But get no result. Could you have a look at it and tell me what is my mistake?

Comment: The tomee embedded task starts a server and wait for exit, were you expecting solething else? Adding -i should show all the startup logs.

Comment: OK, but there is no **war file** on the **webapps** folder(Tomee embedded doesn't deploy to the server) or if i use **exploded** way, which **address** should i type in the browser address bar to run my website(i tried some addresses, but didn't work)? should i do some configuration in the **server.xml** file?

Comment: If you start with -i, the adress is logged normally. Default is localhost:8080. Output also shows what it deploys in info mode.

Answer (score 0):

***what to do***
step1: `gradlew build`
step2: `gradle tomee-embedded -i`

***why*** 
After creating build.gradle file, first task is to run

`gradlew build` command so that it can download required dependencies and plugins, so
please run `gradlew build` and after this run your `TomEE` command.

This Should work,

if using `windows` then command may vary `gradlew.bat build` or for linux, command will be the same as above mentioned `gradlew build`

Comment: Thank you catalystOne. I've tried it before but the error exist and I corrected the error i mentioned. that wasn't right.

Comment: Force tomeeVersion=xxxx in the task configuration (or tomeeembedded config block). Bug is that the default version is loaded from maven metadata but the module renaming was not impacted in code, feel free to fix it with a tomee PR on github, here is the line https://github.com/apache/tomee/blob/master/gradle/gradle-tomee-embedded/src/main/java/org/apache/tomee/gradle/embedded/TomEEEmbeddedPlugin.java#L88